# Phonegap media stops system music

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Phonegap media `play` method has a *magic* option `playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked = false` that does good job:

1. **Prevents** app music from playing when app is **in background**;
2. Makes app music **obey** the hardware **"mute" button**: without this option your app will ignore if user device is muted and play sound anyway.

But there is third hidden magic in this option. It **stops current playing song** from native Music app. Most of all it's annoying when I want to play short single sound.

Actually I would like to implement this scenario:

1. Music: Check if system music is playing on the app start. If it is not, play my app music, otherwise let user enjoy his own media.
2. Sound FX: Just play my little sound once and don't spoil anything.
3. And never play anything in background and when device is muted! Even if system Music app can let itself do so.

Has anyone managed to do something similar?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2291)

Be aware: simple sound effects are not working in Simulator.

Comment: I found that using this plugin (for an ios app) produces a mixed result: the sound plays at its own (option-set) volume - it ignores device volume and mute, the sound is not played if SoundCloud or itunes are playing and it does not pause them, it does not play in background, except it does overlay Spotify. Not ideal, but it doesn't interfere with other media.